# HTML5 number input 'step' attribute effecting Bootstrap column styling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some number inputs styled with Bootstrap, but if I have *both* a min and max set, without `step="any"` the input size behaves differently.

```
<!-- Has step="any", min, max, and fills up all space -->
<div class="row form-group form-inline">
    <label class="col-md-3">Input: </label>
    <span class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red;">
        <input class="form-control col-md-12" type="number" step="any" min="0" max="100"/>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- Has just min and fills up all space -->
<div class="row form-group form-inline">
    <label class="col-md-3">Input: </label>
    <span class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red;">
        <input class="form-control col-md-12" type="number" min="0"/>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- Has nothing and fills up all space -->
<div class="row form-group form-inline">
    <label class="col-md-3">Input: </label>
    <span class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red;">
        <input class="form-control col-md-12" type="number"/>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- Has a step that is not "any", min, max, and does not fill up the space -->
<div class="row form-group form-inline">
    <label class="col-md-3">Input: </label>
    <span class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red;">
        <input class="form-control col-md-12" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="100"/>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- Has both min and max and does not fill up the space -->
<div class="row form-group form-inline">
    <label class="col-md-3">Input: </label>
    <span class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red;">
        <input class="form-control col-md-12" type="number" min="0" max="100"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/47KYE7BjVzFydqFuMi6O?p=preview (You may need to expand the frame size to see the issue)

Answer (score 0):

This may be browser specific behavior.

When `max` and `step` attributes are set, Chrome browser may display a **narrower** input box for `number` input type, as the length of the largest valid value **is limited**.
Also on Chrome,  the Up and Down GUI spinner widget **takes space** from total width of input.